# If I use Azure AD, is it possible that I can create a group of users, and within the group, different users gain access to different resources?

Tags: azure-active-directory

If I were to use Azure AD instead, is it possible that I can create a group of users, and within the group, different users gain access to different resources (yes/no)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you can assign different [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) role to the user to access different resources. **It doesn't matter if they're in the same group**.

You just need to go to the resource first, click "Access Control(IAM)". Then add role assignment to the user.

[image]